# Multiple Conditions not working

Tags: python, operators, conditional-statements

I have the following code

```
if "[FAILED]" in line and (("Result:" not in line) or ("Date:" not in line)):
    print line
```

I'm reading a text file line by line.  I want to look for anywhere in the text file "[FAILED] but it cant have "Result:" or "Date:" in the same line.

My code currently prints out the line even it has result or date in it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to paint the truth table for your expression..then you will find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `and` between the conditions in the parentheses.

Boolean logic is tricky, and if often helps to go through with examples. Consider this line:

```
FAILED blah blah Date: blah
```

So, going through your conditions one by one:

- Failed is in the line, so let's check the next condition.
- "Result:" is not in the line, so that part is true.
- We've got an OR, and we already have a True result, so there's no need to even check if "Date:" is in the line.
- So both sides of the AND are true, so the whole thing is true.

Obviously, exactly the same would happen if the line contained "Result:" but not "Date:".

If you had AND inside the parens, it would need to check that *both* "Date" was not in the line and "Result" is not in the line, rather than being happy if *either* were not there.

A different way to express the condition which might be clearer is this:

```
if "[FAILED]" in line and not (("Result:" in line) or ("Date:" in line)):
```

Comment: I just realized this too... ;)  silly mistake.  Thanks for all the help.  I'll mark your response as the answer in a bit.